# Charging laptop via USB-C from different power sources

Tags: usb-c

I have a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablet Gen 3) that charges via a USB-C port. The power adapter that the laptop came with plugs into the wall outlet and has a USB-C plug on the other end. It provides 65 watts of power.

I am wondering if it is safe to charge the laptop with the power adapter for my iPad Pro 11", (18 watts) which also charges via USB-C. Since the power supplied by the iPad power plug is far less than what the X1 tablet requires, I am wondering if it could cause damage to the X1 tablet's battery?

Along the same lines would damage occur if I tried charging the X1 tablet with a USB battery pack (like 4.5 amp Anker PowerCore 20100) using a USB-C to USB-A cable?

Answer (score 0):

It is a whole different adapter - different voltage.  Please use the proper adapter for this machine. I have an X1 I am working on here